# Accessing list in drools which are created runtime

Tags: java, drools

I have a situation, I need to dynamically add rules in drools. If its a simple rule I can create a string for the same and add it into `knowledgebase`, but there is a situation where I need to include a list as part of the rule, which will also be created dynamically. Adding the rule and adding the list will happen as different events.

I thought of having a `hashmap<String, List<String>>` where key is the name of the list, now I want to know, is there way to access the hashmap, retrieve the list using the list name, and use in `when` criteria of drools as:

```
$pojo:Pojo($listOfString : list1, $listOfString contains input)
```

while adding the rule into drools.

And far as I know, even having a general name for the list in pojo wont work, as during `fireRule`, the drools will be totally confused in choosing the list to be used, and if I assign value to the list while firing rule, then for each rule he will use same list, and result will be as not expected.

Or if there is any other way of achieving the same, please tell me.

I am using drools 5.1

Comment: All facts are created and inserted into WM at runtime, so that your list or lists wouldn't be unusual. If you have  that Map, you can write Java code in an eval CE to extract a List by its key and test for the presence of a String. Your sample code for the Pojo pattern doesn't indicate that there is a Map.

Comment: @laune i agree to this fact, but the problem is i wont fire single rule but instead a bunch of rules, each needing different list against which string has to be evaluated. So even if i fill the fact during run time, i can enter only one list and not the hashmap(that's what i have known so far) if you know a way we can pass a hashmap,  and deduct required list and evaluate the input against it,  please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch a query for an element in one of the lists by inserting a Query fact containing the list identification and the element value. eval should work in 5.1.1, IIRC. You may have to guard against there being no List for key x to avoid a NPE.

```
rule "is element y in list with key x"
when
    Query( $x: key, $y: element )
    Pojo( $map: map )
    eval( $map.get($x).contains( $y ) )
then
    ...
end
```

Comment: what is `Query` in this example, is it a keyword in drools? As when i try to use this i get error `Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Query'`

Comment: Of course it's undefined. It is meant to be declared as a Java class and instantiated with key and expected value and inserted into WM.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to achieve the same with a slightly different rule formation, but all thanks to @laune for showing the right way. The rule can be written as:

```
rule "is element value in list with key key1"
when
    pojo: Pojo($map:map)
    entry: Entry() from $map.entrySet()
    value : String() from entry.getValue()
    key1 : String() from entry.getKey()
    Boolean(booleanValue == true) from (value == pojo.input && key1 == pojo.key)
then
    ........
end
```

here `input` is the element we want to search in the list, and `key1` is the name of the list in which the input has to be searched.

**EDIT**

`pojo.key` wont be used, as the list name will be already set when creating the rule, so the only variable will be String(pojo.value) against which the List has to be evaluated.

Comment: That's a very much inflated variant of what I've posted. - You've added fields key and input to  Pojo, which is probably not a good idea because it puts transaction data into an object containing non-volatile lookup data. You can access fields of an object without using "from" all over. And the Boolean(booleanValue) is a blown-up variant of writing an eval CE.

Comment: @laune I have added key and input into the pojo because, while creating the rule dynamically, it will throw an error while parsing the rule, is there a way to avoid it?(may be Query is the thing which should do that, but i am really clueless about it :( ) And about eval somewhere i read that it should be avoided as much as you can

Comment: I can't comment on "throw an error" because I know neither the text of the rule nor the error reported by the DRL compiler. - Avoiding eval is good if it can be avoided by writing constraints that access fact fields in the regular way. Escaping into contorted code is not the way to go. Actually, the "from (value ==...key)" is just as bad as an eval.